# Examples for Formatters in pyexcel

Tags: python, xlwt, pyexcel

I am working on a project, where we are replacing xlwt with pyexcel. with xlwt, there are a bunch of ways to style cells, columns etc. in pyexcel, there are a bunch of references of formatters like:

```
sheet.column.format(col_index, formatter=some_object)
```

but I can't find a reference of what these objects are. Also, there are references to datatypes, but I am not sure what the valid values are for said data types.

any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for excel files, by default, numbers are always read as float, you can converted them to string  following:

`sheet.column.format(0, str)`

As for `formatter = some_object`, I think you can use any datatype keywords provided by python like `float,str...`.
I hoped this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, My question is more regarding all of the options. are str and float the only options? can I pass any value based type as a datatype? can I use int? decimal?

Comment: I think `int` is ok, decimal is not the basic datatype of python, you have to import decimal package(`from decimal import Decimal`) before using it, however, I didn't use `decimal` in pyexcel.

Comment: the second parameter can be a function whose input will be a cell iterated from the column, whose output shall be the data type you desire and whose conversion is your own responsibility. http://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/generated/pyexcel.sheets.NamedColumn.format.html#pyexcel.sheets.NamedColumn.format

Comment: Are monetary types available?  I mean I want to place a number saying its a monetary value.